# Crear un archivo dump de mysql (que está en el servidor) que baje a mi computadora

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos mysql almacenada en un servidor, me conecto a ella desde mi computadora para trabajar, mi computadora y el servidor son diferentes máquinas en distintos lugares fisicamente, tengo la necesidad de estar creando respaldos de la base de datos por medio de comandos en la consola desde mi maquina, quiero que el archivo de respaldo (dump) por ejemplo respaldo.sql se haga mediante el comando "mysqldump" pero que se baje automáticamente a un directorio de mi computadora local. Ya probé con el comando siguiente y funciona bien pero me crear el archivo de respaldo en el servidor.

```
mysqldump -u countier -p countier > bdcountier.sql
```

¿Cómo se le pone al comando para que lo baje al disco duro de mi computadora local?

Comment: ¿Cómo te conectas desde tu computadora al servidor? ¿Con SSH, telnet, escritorio remoto o el propio `mysqldump`?

Comment: desde mi computadora al servidor con ssh

Comment: Pues ahí tienes el problema: al conectarte por SSH el computador local es el servidor. Prueba con el `mysqldump` directamente desde tu computador, sin SSH

Comment: eso era gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que estaba ejecutando el comando conectándome al servidor, si lo ejecuto desde mi maquina local si guarda el archivo en mi maquina local.